# How to filter a query by columns only if another condition is met

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have a query:

```
query = Usage.query.filter_by(site_id=self.site_id, invoice_num=self.invoice_num, supply_charge=self.supply_charge)
```

And want to filter by dates:

```
.filter(Usage.start_date>four_months_ago)
```

only if the row getting filtered has the same value:

```
if subtotal == self.subtotal
```

Is there a better way of doing this than making a for loop? It seems very inefficient.

```
for row in query.all():
    if self.start_date > four_months_ago:
        if row.subtotal != self.subtotal:
            del row
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Condition

```
(subtotal == self.subtotal) & (Usage.start_date > four_months_ago)
```

looks like

```
WHERE start_date > 'val1' AND subtotal = val2
```

otherwise, `OR subtotal != val2`. You can try to use `or_` + `and_`. Just an example:

```
subtotal = 1
for user in Usage.query.filter(
    Usage.site_id == 2,
    Usage.invoice_num == 3,
    Usage.supply_charge == 4,
    or_(
        and_(Usage.start_date > for_month_ago, Usage.subtotal == subtotal),
        Usage.subtotal != subtotal,
    )
):
    print(user)
```